# Postgres copy data & evaluate expression

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb, postgresql-copy

Is it possible a copy command to evaluate expressions upon insertion?

For example consider the following table

```
create table test1  ( a int, b int)
```

and we have a file to import

```
5  , case when b = 1 then 100 else 101
25 , case when b = 1 then 100 else 101
145, case when b = 1 then 100 else 101
```

The following command fill fail

```
COPY test1 FROM 'file' USING DELIMITERS ',';
```

with the following error

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer

which means that it can not evaluate the case expression. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you build that file yourself?

Comment: Yes, it is the output of a migration script

Answer (score 1):

The command `COPY` only copies data (obviously) and does not evaluate SQL code, as explained in the documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-copy.html

As far as I know there is not workarounds to making COPY evaluating sql code.

You must preprocess your csv file and convert it to a standard sql script with `INSERT` statements in this form:

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES(145, CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 100 ELSE 101 END);
```

Then execute the sql script with the client you are using. I.e. with `psql` you would use the `-f` option:

```
psql -d your_database -f your_sql_script
```

Comment: Yes, i know that it works with insert statements, i checked the copy command for performance reasons

Comment: Well, the short answer is 'No, there is not a workaround' (AFAIK)